# Unexpected fail with marshalling/unmarshalling time object in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

Unmarshalling a marshalled time object is failing, because of a few characters

**Test**

declare the following:

```
// values
now := time.Now()
timeToJSON, _ := json.Marshal(now)
var obj time.Time
json.Unmarshal(timeToJSON, &obj)
```

then do the following test logic:

```
if !assert.Equal(t,
    now.String(),
    obj.String()) {
    t.FailNow()
}
```

**Expected**

the test to pass, and the two objects to be equal

**Actual**

It fails:

```
--- FAIL: TestFromJSON (0.00s)
    D:\dev2017\GO\src\ezsoft\apiserver_sdk\model\delete\deleteModel_test.go:94: 
            Error Trace:    deleteModel_test.go:94
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: "2018-09-04 10:36:18.3627338 -0400 EDT m=+0.014000801"
                            actual  : "2018-09-04 10:36:18.3627338 -0400 EDT"
                            
                            Diff:
                            --- Expected
                            +++ Actual
                            @@ -1 +1 @@
                            -2018-09-04 10:36:18.3627338 -0400 EDT m=+0.014000801
                            +2018-09-04 10:36:18.3627338 -0400 EDT
            Test:           TestFromJSON
FAIL
FAIL    ezsoft/apiserver_sdk/model/delete   1.336s
Error: Tests failed.
```

**NOTE**

I notice that, upon inspecting the output, that, somehow, some `m=+[blah]` is being appended to expected/actual.

I don't know why, however, and [skimming RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) doesn't give me any hints why.

Comment: The "m=" value is the monotonic portion of the clock. See [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String). This part doesn't get marshaled as JSON, so cannot be unmarshaled.

Comment: The `m` value in a `time.Time` is the monotonic clock addition for improved timing accuracy. You can use `time.Truncate(0)` to eliminate it

Comment: This is a not obvious gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks), the `m` value is the monotonic clock value, which can be removed using [`Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) for comparisons not for the purpose of timing. The `m` field does not match because it is omitted from JSON, it is only generated by `time.Now()`.

Try like so:

```
// values
now := time.Now().Truncate(0)  // Truncate to remove monotonic clock portion
timeToJSON, _ := json.Marshal(now)
var obj time.Time
json.Unmarshal(timeToJSON, &obj)
```

The monotonic clock offset was added in order to allow for accurate timing of durations which span a wall clock change (e.g. NTP update, DST change, or leap second/smear).

Answer (score 2):

`time.String()` is not a reliable way to testing a time's value (unless you care about the monotonic clock value, as well).  From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String) (Emphasis added):

> ## func (Time) String
>
> ```
> func (t Time) String() string
> ```
>
> String returns the time formatted using the format string
>
> ```
> "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
> ```
>
> If the time has a monotonic clock reading, the returned string includes a final field "m=±", where value is the monotonic clock reading formatted as a decimal number of seconds.
>
> **The returned string is meant for debugging; for a stable serialized representation, use t.MarshalText, t.MarshalBinary, or t.Format with an explicit format string.**

For your use-case, it would be better to use the output of `time.MarshalText()`instead of `time.String()`:

```
expected, _ := now.MarshalText()
actual, _ := obj.MarshalText()

if !assert.Equal(string(expected), string(actual)) ...
```